# Can open a program in IDLE but not in Terminal,Atom etc

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I'm new to python and pygame but I am using Atom but I can't solve this problem. When I open my script in IDLE it works but I can't make it work on Atom (specifically terminal-plus) and Terminal. My error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cargame.py", line 32, in <module>
    carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
pygame.error: Failed loading libpng.dylib: dlopen(libpng.dylib, 2): image not found
```

so can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the reason why pygame can't load the image is because it has no context of where the module is being loaded from. Make sure the module (*essentially the file where your source code exists*), and image file exist in the same environment on disk (*the same folder*). Otherwise pass an absolute path to the load function and see if the image can be located.

Comment: like putting the image file into the path where pygame is? Also I tried putting the full path to the img but it didn't work

Comment: Also it worked when I changed the file to a .bmp. So problem solved!  ^^